# How to impute missing values based on other variables

Tags: python, pandas, missing-data

I have a dataframe like below:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'one' : pd.Series(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd','aa','bb',np.nan,'b','c',np.nan, np.nan] ), 
  'two' : pd.Series([10, 20, 30, 40,50,60,10,20,30,40,50])} )
```

[image: dataframe]

In which first column is the variables, second column is the values. Variable value is constant, which will never change.

example **'a' value is 10**, **whenever 'a' is presented corrsponding value will be10**

Here some values missing in first column **eg: NaN 10 which is a, NaN 40 which is d** like wise dataframe contains 200 variables.

**Values are not continuous variables, those are discrete and unsortable**

In this case how can we impute missing values.
Expected output should be :

[image: Expected output]

**Please help me on this.**

Regards,
Venkat.

Answer (score 3):

I think in general it would be better to group and fill. We use [`DataFrame.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html):

```
df.groupby('two').apply(lambda x: x.ffill().bfill())
```

---

It can be done without using groupby but you have to sort by both columns:

```
df.sort_values(['two','one']).ffill().sort_index()
```

---

> Below I show you how the method proposed in another answer may fail:

**Here is an example:**

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'one':['a',np.nan,'c','d',np.nan,'c','b','b',np.nan,'a'],'two':[10,20,30,40,10,30,20,20,30,10]})
print(df)

   one  two
0    a   10
1  NaN   20
2    c   30
3    d   40
4  NaN   10
5    c   30
6    b   20
7    b   20
8  NaN   30
9    a   10
```

---

```
df.sort_values(['two']).fillna(method='ffill').sort_index()


  one  two
0   a   10
1   a   20
2   c   30
3   d   40
4   a   10
5   c   30
6   b   20
7   b   20
8   c   30
9   a   10
```

As you can see the proposed method in another of the answers fails here(**see row 1**). This occurs because some NaN Value can be the first for a specific value of the column 'two' and is filled with the value of the upper group.

This don't happen if we group first:

```
df.groupby('two').apply(lambda x: x.ffill().bfill())

  one  two
0   a   10
1   b   20
2   c   30
3   d   40
4   a   10
5   c   30
6   b   20
7   b   20
8   c   30
9   a   10
```

---

As I said we can use [`DataFrame.sort_values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) ​​but we need to sort for both columns.**I recommend you this method**.

```
df.sort_values(['two','one']).ffill().sort_index()

  one  two
0   a   10
1   b   20
2   c   30
3   d   40
4   a   10
5   c   30
6   b   20
7   b   20
8   c   30
9   a   10
```

Comment: Hi @ansev thanks for quick response, but here Values are not continuous variables, those are discrete and unsortable..

Answer (score 1):

Here it is:

```
df.ffill(inplace=True)
```

output:

```
   one  two
0    a   10
1    b   20
2    c   30
3    d   40
4   aa   50
5   bb   60
6    a   10
7    b   20
8    c   30
9    d   40
10  aa   50
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
df = df.sort_values(['two']).fillna(method='ffill').sort_index()
```

Which will give you

```
   one  two
0    a   10
1    b   20
2    c   30
3    d   40
4   aa   50
5   bb   60
6    a   10
7    b   20
8    c   30
9    d   40
10  aa   50
```

Comment: this is fine for a case but it doesn't work in general as I show in my answer

Comment: Hi @strawdog thanks for helping, but here Values are not continuous variables, those are discrete and unsortable.. – Venkat

Comment: @Venkat, can you elaborate on this in your queston?